# Sort a container with a lambda with captured value

Tags: c++

I'm trying to declare a std::set with a compare function to specify the order of elements by using a lambda with a captured value.

I've tried creating a lambda with the captured value an pass that lambda as a templated argument to the std::set.
I've also tried with a functor, and could't make it work either.

```
//Using a lambda

int value = 3; //This is not known at compile time

std::function cmp = [&value](int a, int b){
   return value > 123 ? a < b : a >= b;
};

std::set<int, cmp> mySet;

// Using a functor

class Cmp{
    int value;
public:
    Cmp(int value) : value(value){}; 
    bool operator()(const int&a, const int& b){
        return value > 123 ? a < b : a >= b;
    }
};

int val = 3; //This is not known at compile time

Cmp cmp(val);
set<int, cmp> mySet;
```

I get this error when using the lambda:

> note: a lambda closure type has a deleted default constructor

And this one when using the functor:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘Cmp::Cmp()’

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't pass a runtime variable in a template parameter.

The `Compare` template parameter of `std:set` expects a typename, not a variable.  The actual comparison function matching the typename can be passed to the `set::set` constructor.

Try this instead:

```cpp
//Using a lambda

int value = 3; //This is not known at compile time

auto cmp = [&value](int a, int b){
   return value > 123 ? a < b : a >= b;
};

std::set<int, decltype(cmp)> mySet(cmp);
```

```cpp
//Using a functor

class MySetComparer{
    int value;
public:
    MySetComparer(int value) : value(value) {}
    bool operator()(int a, int b) const {
        return value > 123 ? a < b : a >= b;
    }
};

int val = 3; //This is not known at compile time

MySetComparer cmp(val);
set<int, MySetComparer/*decltype(cmp)*/> mySet(cmp);
```

NOTE: either way, do be aware that your comparer's use of `a >= b` breaks [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) of the [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) requirement used by standard C++ containers:

> The return value of the function call operation applied to an object of a type satisfying *Compare*, when contextually converted to `bool`, yields `true` if **the first argument of the call appears before the second** in the *strict weak ordering relation* induced by this type, and `false` otherwise.

`a < b` satisfies that requirement, but `a >= b` does not, which will cause *Undefined Behavior* in your code at runtime when `value > 123` is not true.

Comment: You should mention that using `a >= b` leads to UB

Comment: Thank you very much, I did forget the decltype, but I didn't know that you had to pass the object to the constructor! Thanks again!

Comment: @Slava I added it